# Name Error in Random Generator Function

Tags: python-3.x, bioinformatics

Here, I have a code that from an inputted dna strand, I generate 100 mutated strands at a frequency of 0.66%. The output ends up being a tuple of mutated bases paired with the original base in the initial strand. The function itself worked initially, but once I placed it in a class, I got an error:

```
import random

class DNA_mutant_generator:
    def __init__ (self, dna):
        self.dna = dna
        dna = "GGCTCTCCAACAGgtaagcactgaagggtagaaggcatcgtctgtctcagacatgtctggcaccatccgctaagacattaccacgtgggtctcgagtatagctaacacccttctgtttggcagCTTACAGGAGCGAACGTTGG"

    def mutate(mutation_rate=0.0066):
        result = []
        mutations = []
        for base in dna:
            if random.random() < mutation_rate:
                new_base = bases[bases.index(base) - random.randint(1, 3)] # negatives are OK
                result.append(new_base)
                mutations.append((base, new_base))#appends the original base, as well as the new mutated base to a list of tuples
            else:
                result.append(base)
        return "".join(result), mutations

        for result_string, mutations in results:
            if mutations: # skip writing out unmutated strings
                print(result_string, mutations)    

results = [DNA_mutant_generator.mutate(dna) for _ in range(100)]


dna_mutants = DNA_mutant_generator()
dna_mutants.mutate()
```

The error looks like this:

```
results = [DNA_mutant_generator.mutate(dna) for _ in range(100)]
NameError: global name 'dna' is not defined
```

But I did define what "dna" was in **init**. Could somebody explain why I'm not getting a proper input?

EDIT: with the change, I get this error:

```
new_base = bases[bases.index(base) - random.randint(1, 3)]     # negatives are OK
               NameError: global name 'bases' is not defined
```

EDIT 2:

I changed my code to look like this.:

```
import random

class DNA_mutant_generator:
    def __init__ (self, dna):
        self.dna = dna
        self.bases = bases

    def mutate(mutation_rate=0.0066):
        result = []
        mutations = []
        for base in self.dna:
            if random.random() < mutation_rate:
                new_base = bases[bases.index(base) - random.randint(1, 3)] # negatives are OK
                result.append(new_base)
                mutations.append((base, new_base))#appends the original base, as well as the new mutated base to a list of tuples
            else:
                result.append(base)
        return "".join(result), mutations

        for result_string, mutations in results:
            if mutations: # skip writing out unmutated strings
                print(result_string, mutations)    
bases = "ACTG"
dna = "GGCTCTCCAACAGgtaagcactgaagggtagaaggcatcgtctgtctcagacatgtctggcaccatccgctaagacattaccacgtgggtctcgagtatagctaacacccttctgtttggcagCTTACAGGAGCGAACGTTGG"
dna_mutants = DNA_mutant_generator(dna)
dna_mutants.mutate()
results = [DNA_mutants.mutate() for _ in range(100)]
```

And the error that i get is as such:

```
    for base in self.dna:
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: Where are you getting dna to pass into mutate?  Since this is being called from the global scope and the only instance of dna you have is within the class scope.   I would move dna right above: results = [DNA_mutant_generator.mutate(dna) for _ in range(100)].

Comment: where do you define bases[] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is so much wrong with your code it is hard to know where to start:

1. The last line of `__init__` doesn't do anything;
2. The `mutate` method:

   1. lacks the `self` argument;
   2. tries to access `bases`, which you never define;
   3. has orphaned code after the `return` - the method ends when you return, so any code in the method *after* the return statement will *never run**; and
   4. doesn't use `self.att` when accessing e.g. `dna` (hence the `NameError`);
3. You don't create a `DNA_mutant_generator` instance when trying to create `results`, instead trying to call an instance method on the class - and you pass `dna` to the wrong thing; and
4. The last two lines do try to create an instance, but again don't pass `dna`.

Try:

```
import random

class DNA_mutant_generator:

    BASES = "ACGT" # access via 'self.BASES'

    def __init__ (self, dna):
        self.dna = dna

    def mutate(self, mutation_rate=0.0066):
        result = []
        mutations = []
        for base in self.dna:
            ...
        return "".join(result), mutations


dna = "GGCTCTCCAACAG..."
mutant_gen = DNA_mutant_generator(dna)
results = [mutant_gen.mutate() for _ in range(100)]
```

You really need to review the [Python tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

* *in your case this is probably just as well because, for reasons that are unclear, the lines in question attempt to iterate over `results` before you actually create it.*

Comment: Thanks. but with that, I get another error - I'll just post it in my question above.

Comment: @user3670902 yes, because you don't define `bases` anywhere. This isn't magic, you need to tell Python what to do. I suggest making it a class attribute.

Comment: @user3670902 I have edited my answer to give one option for defining `bases`. As I comment at the end, you need to read the tutorial on classes at a minimum; you really don't seem to be getting it.

Comment: ok, but why do I need to say "for base in self.dna" when I've already said self.dna = dna?

Comment: @user3670902 you need to actually learn the language; you can't just type and hope for the best. I recommend Mark Lutz's ["Learning Python"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028154.do), but I hear good things about ["Learn Python the Hard Way"](http://learnpythonthehardway.org), too.

Comment: I just tend to overlook a lot of syntax stuff. Yes, I know that I am supposed to define bases, but sometimes, when the error message does not say what I did wrong specifically, it's easy to get lost in the code. For instance, I just made a new edit (as shown above), but it says "self" isn't defined.

Comment: @user3670902 as I've told you before, don't keep editing your question with each tiny change to your code - it means that the answers may no longer apply. Development by iterative SO comment and low-quality question isn't a good method. In this case, you haven't actually read my answer and made all of the changes I suggest. You can't *"overlook a lot of syntax stuff"* and expect to get anywhere - take it seriously or give up.

Comment: I was actually told that if you input "self.att = att", you don't have to use "self" in the rest of your code. is that wrong?

Comment: @user3670902 yes, complete nonsense. You always need to make `self` the first argument when defining instance methods, and use `self.attr` when referring to class and instance attributes (generally anything but arguments and things you define within the function). The only exception is that in the rest of the method in which you assign `self.attr = attr` you can use either `self.attr` or `attr` (unless you change one of them), as both are in scope (but *only* in that method).

Comment: also, you mentioned that there is "orphaned code" after the return. Can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: Alright. I made some changes, and I think I fixed what you mentioned. however, I still get an error. would it be okay if I post it and you tell me what else I am missing? I thought I included everything, but it's not working just yet.

Comment: @user3670902 I can't tell you whether what you have now makes a good SO question. I can tell you that you've written five low-quality questions in writing what you have so far, and seem unable to fix any error on your own, so I'd guess not. If you go searching for "how to debug" you will find many resources; I suggest you start [here](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).